# GetPrivateProfileString in .NET

Tags: .net, winapi

Is there a .NET version of GetPrivateProfileString?

(I can use p/invoke, I just don't want to unless necessary.)

Comment: Have you considered moving from .INI file to XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not built in, no.  There's nothing that can natively read and understand the layout of an .ini file in .NET.  GetPrivateProfileString is your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't, at least not in the Base Class Library.  This isn't surprizing, given that .NET doesn't have any native support (in the form of pure managed code, or wrappers over P/Invoke calls) for INI files.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to use Interop, you can use ini file loader class like this one

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/INI_Files.aspx

Comment: Not exactly what I had in mind, but definitely something to consider if I find myself keeping the ini files longer that I had planned.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are limited to working with the existing `.ini` files you should consider using [TOML](https://toml.io/en/) format which has a syntax very similar to `.ini` but better.

One of the good TOML parsers for .Net is [Tomlet](https://github.com/SamboyCoding/Tomlet/).

Note that TOML parser can in theory also be used to parse `.ini` files although I don't recommend doing that.

Comment: As it so happens, I've been looking at TOML for my next project. I'm really liking what I'm seeing so far.